# spring boot 3.0 repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot 3. In Spring Boot 3.0 version data jpa, pagingAndSortingRepository seems to inherit Repository and CrudRepository in other versions, is this a change in 3.0?

Then, how do I use the same method as save in 3.0?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Yes, those [are now decoupled](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2537) since Spring Data Commons [3.0-M2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/releases/tag/3.0.0-M2) as we now have [`CrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) and [`ListCrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/data/repository/ListCrudRepository.html) as well as [`PagingAndSortingRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) and [`ListPagingAndSortingRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/data/repository/ListPagingAndSortingRepository.html)

See the docs for the intended usage: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts

> Additional you can extend `PagingAndSortingRepository` (...) if you need methods that allow to specify a `Sort` abstraction or in the first case a `Pageable` abstraction. Note that the various sorting repositories no longer extended their respective CRUD repository as they did in Spring Data Versions pre 3.0. Therefore, you need to extend both interfaces if you want functionality of both.

In other words, extend both (List)CrudRepository AND a (List)PagingAndSortingRepository if you want these methods in Spring Data 3.0+.

Or [you can just use the `Pageable` and `Sort` parameters in your own methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) and they will be correctly picked up by the library.